# ngRepeat not updating even though $resource has

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngresource

I have an "add friend" dialogue, when you add a user it goes back in the state history and should update the friend list. Everything works fine, except that the list doesn't show the new user - even though both `console.log`s show the correct data:

```
[e, e, e, $promise: Promise, $resolved: true]
```

(3 `e`s is correct, I had two before).

```
$scope.add = function (user, goback) {
  if (goback)
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  $ionicLoading.show();
  ApiService.friends.request(user._id, function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
    $scope.users = ApiService.users.friends(function (res, headers) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      console.log($scope.users);
    }); 
    console.log($scope.users);
  }); 
}
```

I tried wrapping the `$scope.users =`  thing in `$scope.$apply` or calling that in various places but that only (rightfully) raises a `$digest already in progress` error (because $resource automaticall does that).

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

---

wtf is going on? I just tried just doing this:

```
$scope.add = function (user, goback) {
  $scope.users = [];
}
```

(and even wrapping `$scope.users = []` in $apply) but nothing happens!
But $scope.add is called from an `ng-click` directive - this should work!

---

## Found the actual Error!

My add-friend view, where `add` was getting called, of course had it's own $scope. It's pretty dirty but I ended up using `$scope.$parent.users` instead of `$scope.users` to hold the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in OP, this was a very basic scope error as I forgot I was actually switching the `ui-router` view between the two actions so my `$scope.users` were actually two different things.

Moving the list to `$scope.$parent.users` fixes it for now, though thinking about it again I should probably move the value into the controller and use the `MyController as ctrl` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same problem recently. Apparently the `$q` promises used by `$resource` only resolve during a `$digest` cycle **by design** (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2881), which is why you get that digest in progress error when using `$scope.$apply`.

A workaround is to wrap your assignment in a `$timeout` to force another digest cycle, e.g.:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.users = ApiService.users.friends(); // Abbreviated
});
```

I'm not 100% sure why you're assigning the result of `ApiService.users.friends()` to `$scope.users` since I'd guess that method returns a promise, but I could be missing larger context.

Comment: `users.friends` is a $resource query (`method: GET, isArray: true`).

Comment: and this still isn't doing anything... any console debug output after the assignment still prints the three-element list though.